# How to place in one widget tree several widgets flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the right way to place all these widgets together? When I tried to place together widget which is building the listview. separated widget and the widgets where I am creating the UI for filters, it draws only widget with filtering items but doesn't create the listview. I was searching that I should place it in the column widget and in the expanded but it also doesn't work as I want.

Here is my code:

```
class _ProductListState extends State<ProductList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var providerGridPagination = Provider.of<ProviderGridProduct>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text("Категории товаров", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),),
        leading: IconButton(onPressed: (){
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()),
          );
        }, icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black45,),),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FiltersWidget(),
          SmartRefresher(
            controller: providerGridPagination.refreshController,
            enablePullUp: true,
            onRefresh: () async {
              final result = await providerGridPagination.getProductData(isRefresh: true);
              if (result) {
                providerGridPagination.refreshController.refreshCompleted();
              } else {
                providerGridPagination.refreshController.refreshFailed();
              }
            },
            onLoading: () async {
              final result = await providerGridPagination.getProductData();
              if (result) {
                providerGridPagination.refreshController.loadComplete();
              } else {
                providerGridPagination.refreshController.loadFailed();
              }
            },
            child: ListView.separated(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                //final gridItems = providerGridPagination.itemgrid[index];
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(providerGridPagination.itemgrid[index].title!),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
              itemCount: providerGridPagination.itemgrid.length,
            ),

          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the error is:

```
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
```

Comment: full of Misspellings. please correct them.

Comment: @reza although SOF requires the OPs to have correct spellings and formal writing, we don't bash people here, not everyone's first language is English as you know, instead you could offer to edit the post! Happy coding!

Comment: okay, I solved this issue by myself. I need to be more careful, because it is not the issue I should post on the SO (read: the stupidest question), so I just divided the entire user interface that I need into different stls widgets, and then in the main widget tree I used Expaneded on the widget that creates the list.